# I am trying to find out a couple of recursion problems in Python 3.*

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, return

I am fairly new at Python and I'm having difficulty understanding how the return statement works in a couple of cases in a recursive function.

The first is:

Why does the "return 10" multiply the ten when the program does not go back through the else test when n becomes 1?
In other words the result of this is: 1200 (or 5*4*3*2*1*10)

```
def test(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 10
    else:
        return n * test(n-1)
print(test(5))
```

Then let me change this a little bit and its result is 24 which means the ten is added to the results below.  I guess I'm just having trouble with how return actually works and how it works when used in a recursion with multiple returns.

```
def test(n):
     if n == 1:
         return 10
     else:
         return n+test(n-1)

print(test(5))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of spending time writing that question, you should have instead spent it on learning the basics of recursion first.

Comment: Also, [so] is not a code explaining site. And you should read the [ask] section

Comment: Thank you.  I do understand recursion because it is a simply a function calling itself.  What I didn't understand was the exact sequence of the calculations that would return the final answer because I overlooked it.  I do apologize for the formatting of the question.  I'm new to your site and when I read it, I failed to grasp all the nuances.  After all I'm old and retired and was just looking for an answer.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why does the "return 10" multiply the ten when the program does not go back through the else test when n becomes 1?*

It's because of `n * test(n-1)`. When n becomes 1 you return 10 and the recursion ends. So `n * test(1)` is like `n * 10`. The same in the second case (but with `+`).

Recursion is calling the same function multiple times. It's easier to understand with different functions. You return a number and stop returning the function again to prevent infinity running code (you'll get a stackoverflow).

```
def test1(n):
    if n == 1:                #n is 3 not 1
        return 10             #skipping
    else:                     #what to do then
        return n * test2(n-1) #return n times a value of another function, calling test2

def test2(n):
    if n == 1:                #n is 2 not 1
        return 10             #skipping
    else:                     #what to do then
        return n * test3(n-1) #return n times a value of another function, calling test3

def test3(n):
    if n == 1:                #n is 1
        return 10             #returning 10
    else:                     #never called
        return n * test4...(n-1)
```

print(test1(3))

At `test3` `test3(n-1)` becomes to `10`. `test2(n-1)` becomes to `n * test3(n-1)` so `n * 10`, in this case `2 * 10`. And `test1(n-1)` becomes to `n * test2(n-1)` so `n * n * 10`, in this case `1 * 2 * 10`.

You see test1, test2 and test3 are the same functions, so you can just call the same without creating another.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That explains it much better because test3 has to be evaluated first to have an answer for test2.  I think that is where my problem occurred.  It was just an oversight on my part.